# Error: SqlException was unhandled by usecode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Getting error while updating data

```
Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
```

my code is

```
 public bool UpdateData(MemberInfo memberinfo)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = DataConnection.GetConnection().CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "prcUpdateMemberInfo";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MemberFirstName", memberinfo.MemberFirstName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MemberMiddleName", memberinfo.MemberMiddleName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MemberLastName", memberinfo.MemberLastName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FatherName", memberinfo.FatherName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MotherName", memberinfo.MotherName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FamilyHeadName", memberinfo.FamilyHeadName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DOB", memberinfo.DOB));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EducationLevelID", memberinfo.EducationLevelID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EducationFieldID", memberinfo.EducationFieldID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BloodGroupID", memberinfo.BloodGroupID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OccupationTypeID", memberinfo.OccupationTypeID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Gender", memberinfo.Gender));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GotraID", memberinfo.GotraID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SectID", memberinfo.SectID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MaritalStatus", memberinfo.MarritalStatus));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HouseNumber", memberinfo.HouseNumber));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StreetName", memberinfo.StreetName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Area", memberinfo.Area));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LandMark", memberinfo.LandMark));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StateID", memberinfo.StateID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CountryID", memberinfo.CountryID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CityID", memberinfo.CityID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailAddress", memberinfo.EmailAddress));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PhoneNumber", memberinfo.PhoneNumber));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", memberinfo.UserId));          
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsSubmit", memberinfo.IsSubmit));
            bool ans = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
            cmd.Dispose();
            DataConnection.CloseConnection();
            return ans;
```

and the procedure is

```
create proc [dbo].[prcUpdateMemberInfo]
(
@UserId uniqueidentifier,
@MemberFirstName varchar(20),
@MemberMiddleName varchar(20),
@MemberLastName varchar(20),
@FamilyHeadName varchar(50),
@FatherName varchar(50),
@MotherName varchar(50),
@DOB datetime,
@GotraID int,
@SectID int,
@BloodGroupID int,
@EducationLevelID int, 
@EducationFieldID int,
@HouseNumber varchar(20),
@StreetName varchar(50),
@Area varchar(50),
@LandMark varchar(50),
@StateID int,
@CountryID int,
@CityID int, 
@PhoneNumber int,
@EmailAddress varchar(50),
@MaritalStatus varchar(20),
@OccupationTypeID int,
@Gender varchar(10),
@IsSubmit bit
)
as
update MemberInfo
set 
MemberFirstName = @MemberFirstName,
MemberMiddleName=@MemberMiddleName ,
MemberLastName =@MemberLastName,
FamilyHeadName =@MemberLastName,
FatherName =@FatherName,
MotherName =@MotherName,
DOB =@DOB,
GotraID =@GotraID,
SectID =@SectID,
BloodGroupID =@BloodGroupID,
EducationLevelID =@EducationLevelID,
EducationFieldID =@EducationFieldID,
HouseNumber =@HouseNumber,
StreetName =@StreetName,
Area =@Area,
LandMark =@LandMark,
StateID =@StateID,
CountryID=@CountryID,
CityID =@CityID,
PhoneNumber =@PhoneNumber,
EmailAddress =@EmailAddress,
MaritalStatus =@MaritalStatus,
OccupationTypeID=@OccupationTypeID,
Gender=@Gender,
IsSubmit=@IsSubmit
where UserId =@UserId
```

the class is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace JaiJinendera.Common
{
    public class MemberInfo
    {
        string  memberFirstName, memberMiddleName, memberLastName, fatherName, motherName, familyHeadName, gender, marritalStatus,phoneNumber, houseNumber, landMark, area, streetName, emailAddress;

        public string EmailAddress
        {
            get { return emailAddress; }
            set { emailAddress = value; }
        }

        public string StreetName
        {
            get { return streetName; }
            set { streetName = value; }
        }

        public string Area
        {
            get { return area; }
            set { area = value; }
        }

        public string LandMark
        {
            get { return landMark; }
            set { landMark = value; }
        }

        public string HouseNumber
        {
            get { return houseNumber; }
            set { houseNumber = value; }
        }

        public string MarritalStatus
        {
            get { return marritalStatus; }
            set { marritalStatus = value; }
        }

        public string Gender
        {
            get { return gender; }
            set { gender = value; }
        }

        public string FamilyHeadName
        {
            get { return familyHeadName; }
            set { familyHeadName = value; }
        }

        public string MotherName
        {
            get { return motherName; }
            set { motherName = value; }
        }

        public string FatherName
        {
            get { return fatherName; }
            set { fatherName = value; }
        }

        public string MemberLastName
        {
            get { return memberLastName; }
            set { memberLastName = value; }
        }

        public string MemberMiddleName
        {
            get { return memberMiddleName; }
            set { memberMiddleName = value; }
        }

        public string MemberFirstName
        {
            get { return memberFirstName; }
            set { memberFirstName = value; }
        }

        int countryID, stateID, cityID, sectID, gotraID, educationLevelID, educationFieldID, bloodGroupID, occupationTypeID;

        public int OccupationTypeID
        {
            get { return occupationTypeID; }
            set { occupationTypeID = value; }
        }


        public string PhoneNumber
        {
            get { return phoneNumber; }
            set { phoneNumber = value; }
        }

        public int BloodGroupID
        {
            get { return bloodGroupID; }
            set { bloodGroupID = value; }
        }

        public int EducationFieldID
        {
            get { return educationFieldID; }
            set { educationFieldID = value; }
        }

        public int EducationLevelID
        {
            get { return educationLevelID; }
            set { educationLevelID = value; }
        }

        public int GotraID
        {
            get { return gotraID; }
            set { gotraID = value; }
        }

        public int SectID
        {
            get { return sectID; }
            set { sectID = value; }
        }

        public int CityID
        {
            get { return cityID; }
            set { cityID = value; }
        }

        public int StateID
        {
            get { return stateID; }
            set { stateID = value; }
        }

        public int CountryID
        {
            get { return countryID; }
            set { countryID = value; }
        }
        DateTime dOB, insertionDate;

        public DateTime InsertionDate
        {
            get { return insertionDate; }
            set { insertionDate = value; }
        }

        public DateTime DOB
        {
            get { return dOB; }
            set { dOB = value; }
        }
        Guid userId;


public Guid UserId
{
  get { return userId; }
  set { userId = value; }
}
bool isSubmit;

public bool IsSubmit
{
    get { return isSubmit; }
    set { isSubmit = value; }
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Well to get an answer you should show the definition of the class MemberInfo. As the message says one of your parameters values is passed as a string but an integer is expected (two cents on PhoneNumber)

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory, have you tried to solve this yourself yet?

Comment: yaaaaa from last few hours i am trying only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have said in my comment, in the class definition PhoneNumber is a string but the stored procedure expects an integer. This is your problem.

I would change the stored procedure and the underlying datatable to a VARCHAR(30) or a size of your like because it is possible to have phone numbers with alphabetical characters. Otherwise, if you are absolutely sure of the contrary change the class declaration to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure has `@PhoneNumber int` which should probably be `@PhoneNumber varchar(50)` or some other varchar length.